# Are AppCompat frameworks and libraries necessary for new Android projects?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm just getting into Android development. I'll be using Xamarin.Android. Reading into this, and having toyed around with Android in the past, are AppCompat frameworks/libraries still necessary? I ask this because it seems that from Nov 1, 2019, all new app submissions require at least API Level 28 as the minimum, so what use would it be to include all these bloated appcompat libraries?

Correct me if I'm wrong or mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

@wpa 
`AppCompat` should not be necessary if you are starting a fresh new project. You can start using `AndroidX` libraries which will provide backwards compatibility. The requirement being mandated starting `Nov 1, 2019` is not for the `minimumSdk`. It is for the `targetSdk` version. These are different. You can still have your `minimumSdk` to the lowest you want, but your app should target at least `Android 8.0 (API level 26)`.
Please follow the link below for detailed information.

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Google requires set `targetSdkVersion` api level in 28 for currently apps in the Google Play Store, but if you are starting a new project, surely will start by default withe the latest android version 29.

Feel free of choose the `minSdkVersion` in your project.

`targetSdkVersion`: normally the latest android version available (for example API 29/Android 10)

`minSdkVersion`: the min Android SDK that your application can run on (for example since 21/ Android Lollipop)

**androidx**

Other hand, it is still necessary to support previous versions if your plan is to reach the majority of users using new features in old versions of android

However, according to android documentation, developers should be start projects using androidx libraries and not use appcompat library anymore.

> Artifacts within the androidx namespace comprise the Android Jetpack libraries. Like the Support Library, libraries in theandroidx namespace ship separately from the Android platform and provide backward compatibility across Android releases.

- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx
- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions/
- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate (if in the future you find an old project that needs to migrate to androidx libraries)

Comment: Ah, I was originally under the impression what Google was referring that the minimum SDK version was to be set to Level 28.

Comment: Oh I see, Google requires set `targetSdkVersion` api level in 28, but if you are starting a new project, surely will start in 29. Feel free of choose the `minSdkVersion` in your project.

`targetSdkVersion` : normally the latest android version available (for example API 29/Android 10)
`minSdkVersion`: the min Android SDK that your application can run on (for example since 21/ Android Lollipop)